# MS Dynamics CRM work with attachements. show attachment in custom field

Tags: dynamics-crm, attachment

I have a question about attachments. I know that attachment is stored in annotation entity. How can I create a custom field in my entity for displaying the last attached file? If it's possible, then can I not display attachments in "Notes" section?

Comment: I'm not 100% on what the question is.  Is what you are looking to do is to store the contents of an attachment in a text field on the parent entity?

Comment: I would like to create a filed which will be displaying a link to attached file. With that link I will be able to download file.

Comment: Attachments should be downloadable directly from the "Notes" section UI on a form.  What version of dynamics-crm are you using (2011, 4.0, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and found this:
https://mahadeomatre.blogspot.com/2016/10/view-or-download-attachments-for.html

It appears to open a dialog with a list of all the attachments (it looks through each note) and the ability to preview or download.

You may be able to take this and modify it to suit your needs to show only the latest attachment.  Instead of grabbing ALL the attachments, you could just grab the attachment from the latest note.

Instead of opening a dialog, you might also be able to try creating an iframe on your form, since you're only going to have one attachment shown.